# Content files showing up in install directory

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

So I currently have a script that works just fine with one problem. Whenever I publish it as a ClickOnce application, it has to be installed on the users computer before it can be used, and the the files I have specified to run if the user provides a valid login are showing up in the local APPDATA files.

I feel like there has to be a better way to publish my application.  I want the 4 files ( a .swf that will run with flash, a bat file to run those, and a .vbs script that runs the bat file in the background so it doesn't pop up) to be included in the project, but to be written into the resulting binary files, not in their original form so the source is freely available.

Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: How about embedding a Flash Player control in your program and devising some way to to stream your Flash movie from a resource? Alternatively (and much simpler), store your "external" files in a resource ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ) and write them to the Windows temp directory when you need to use them and delete them afterwards.

Comment: Can you explain how you would have the files stream, so that they can be excecuted in a .bat file? The files will be private and I dont want the source code freely available. I currently am using option 2 and the files are easy to find on the users in just my looking in %APPDATA%

Comment: Currently I am using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Run.bat") to excecute a file that is added to the project with its build type set to Content. I want to use the embedded resource